# Fetch array data (from JSON) using dynamic content in loop

Tags: javascript

This is a sample code I'm trying to build. The actual JSON has a lot more data making the "switch" statement portion of the code not very practical to maintain (currently the only way I could make it work).

Is there a way to replace it by something similar to what I used for the other data "Model1" & "Model2" to make use of dynamic data used in the "for" loop?

I created a test at: https://jsfiddle.net/ShaiHul/evrqj1b5/42/

```js
var data = {
  "Car": {
    "wheels": 4,
    "InStock": {
      "Toyota": {
        "Model1": 10,
        "Model2": 5
      },
      "Honda": {
        "Model1": 12,
        "Model2": 3
      }
    }
  },
  "Bicycle": {
    "wheels": 2,
    "InStock": {
      "Toyota": {
        "Model1": 25,
        "Model2": 14
      },
      "Honda": {
        "Model1": 22,
        "Model2": 13
      }
    }
  }
};

var vehicles = [{
    name: "Car"
  },
  {
    name: "Bicycle"
  }
];

for (i in vehicles) {

  var vehicle = vehicles[i].name;

  document.getElementsByClassName(vehicle + "Model1")[0].innerHTML = vehicle + ", Toyota, Model 1: " + data[vehicle].InStock.Toyota["Model1"];
  document.getElementsByClassName(vehicle + "Model2")[0].innerHTML = vehicle + ", Toyota, Model 2: " + data[vehicle].InStock.Toyota["Model2"];

  switch (vehicle) {
    case "Car":
      document.getElementsByClassName(vehicle + "Wheels")[0].innerHTML = vehicle + ", Toyota, Wheels: " + data.Car["wheels"];
      break;
    case "Bicycle":
      document.getElementsByClassName(vehicle + "Wheels")[0].innerHTML = vehicle + ", Toyota, Wheels: " + data.Bicycle["wheels"];
      break;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="CarModel1"></div>
<div class="CarModel2"></div>
<div class="CarWheels"></div>
<br/>
<div class="BicycleModel1"></div>
<div class="BicycleModel2"></div>
<div class="BicycleWheels"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure thing! Your switch statement can go from this:

```
switch (vehicle) {
  case "Car":
    document.getElementsByClassName(vehicle + "Wheels")[0].innerHTML = vehicle + ", Toyota, Wheels: " + data.Car["wheels"];
    break;
  case "Bicycle":
    document.getElementsByClassName(vehicle + "Wheels")[0].innerHTML = vehicle + ", Toyota, Wheels: " + data.Bicycle["wheels"];
    break;
}
```

to this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(vehicle + "Wheels")[0].innerHTML =
    vehicle + ", Toyota, Wheels: " + data[vehicle]["wheels"];
```

The key part in this new form is the `data[vehicle]["wheels"]` section, at the very end. Instead of using known object properties `Car` and `Wheel`, just use the variable `vehicle` which should be set to the string `Car` or `Bicycle`, which are also the property names in the json `data` you have at the top of your question.

So your entire `for-loop` would just look like this in the end:

```
for (i in vehicles) {
  var vehicle = vehicles[i].name;

  document.getElementsByClassName(vehicle + "Model1")[0].innerHTML = vehicle + ", Toyota, Model 1: " + data[vehicle].InStock.Toyota["Model1"];
  document.getElementsByClassName(vehicle + "Model2")[0].innerHTML = vehicle + ", Toyota, Model 2: " + data[vehicle].InStock.Toyota["Model2"];

  // new line, replacing your switch statement
  document.getElementsByClassName(vehicle + "Wheels")[0].innerHTML =
    vehicle + ", Toyota, Wheels: " + data[vehicle]["wheels"];
}
```

Comment: I'll be damned! I did try exactly that before submitting the question and it wasn't working. Tried it again now and boom working. Must have another issue in the actual code. Coz working with the fiddle sample. Thanks!

Comment: @ShaiHul Haha dang, well I'm glad this is working for ya :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and loop through them like this to get any dynamic `data` at any position:

```js
var data={"Car":{"wheels":4,"InStock":{"Toyota":{"Model1":10,"Model2":5},"Honda":{"Model1":12,"Model2":3}}},"Bicycle":{"wheels":2,"InStock":{"Toyota":{"Model1":25,"Model2":14},"Honda":{"Model1":22,"Model2":13}}}};

const $vehicles = document.getElementById("vehicles");

Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  Object.entries(value.InStock).forEach(([vehicleName, models]) => {
    Object.entries(models).forEach(([modelName, count], index) => {
      $vehicles.innerHTML += `<div>${key}, ${vehicleName}, Model ${index + 1}: ${count}</div>`
    });
    $vehicles.innerHTML += `<div>${key}, ${vehicleName}, Wheels: ${value.wheels}</div>`;
  });
  
  $vehicles.innerHTML += '<br>' // add a line between vehicle types
});
```

```html
<div id="vehicles">

</div>
```

I'm using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to create the content of each `div`. You can create it using `+` on each string if it's not supported in your browser yet.
Like this:

```
$vehicles.innerHTML += '<div>' + key + ', ' + vehicleName + ', Model ' + (index + 1) + ':' + count + '</div>';
```

[Here's the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3enq8py7/1/)

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3enq8py7/2/) without using template literals

Comment: Thanks, I'm not trying to enumerate the data stream. Every piece of data need to go to a certain <div> section existing on the HTML template. Though I will play with what you submitted to see if I can adapt it.